# Should SEXP function args be PROTECTed when put inside an Rcpp::Xptr?

Tags: r, rcpp

Look at the (oversimplified) `Rcpp` + `R` code below :

**test.cpp** :

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

class VecWrap{
public:
  SEXP vector;
  int type;

  VecWrap(SEXP vector)
  {
    this->vector = vector;
    this->type = TYPEOF(vector);
    if(this->type != INTSXP && this->type != REALSXP)
      stop("invalid type");
  }

  bool contains(double val){
    if(type == INTSXP){
      IntegerVector v = vector;
      for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
        if(v[i] == val)
          return true;
    }else if(type == REALSXP){
      NumericVector v = vector;
      for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
        if(v[i] == val)
          return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
};

// [[Rcpp::export]]
SEXP createVecWrap(SEXP x) {
  VecWrap* w = new VecWrap(x);
  return XPtr< VecWrap >(w);
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
SEXP vecWrapContains(XPtr< VecWrap > w, double val){
  return wrap(w->contains(val));
}
```

**test.R** :

```
library(Rcpp)
sourceCpp(file='test.cpp')

v <- 1:10e7

w <- createVecWrap(v)
vecWrapContains(w, 10000) # it works

# remove v and call the garbage collector
rm(v)
gc()

vecWrapContains(w, 10000) # R crashes (but it works with small vector "v")
```

Basically I put inside the custom class `VecWrap` the `SEXP` vector received as argument of `createVecWrap` function, in order to use it later.

But, as explained by the comments in the code, if I remove the vector `v` from the R-side and call the garbage collector, the R process crashes when I try to access the vector.
Should the vector be protected by the GC in someway ? If so, how? (Rcpp-style if possible)

Comment: You do not need to write a VectorWrap, just interface directly with the [`Vector`](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp/html/vector_2Vector_8h_source.html) class, which has necessary policy classes setup to protect against garbage collection. The `NumericVector` et al, are all `typedefs` that are run through this class.

Comment: Yes, I know what you mean, but as I said my example is oversimplified; my real needs are much more complex but my issue (i.e. SEXP protection inside a class wrapped in Xptr) can be simplified with this (obviously stupid) example ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally speaking you should try to stick to the C++ type system / Rcpp classes as much as possible (re: avoid handling `SEXP` directly if possible). However, the [`RObject` class](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/blob/6f81b4684481dbd9bb554dd95e66725fc3b63a8c/inst/include/Rcpp/RObject.h#L27-L58) will provide your `SEXP` with protection from the garbage collector, and seems to work in this case:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

class VecWrap {
public:
    Rcpp::RObject vector;
    int type;

    VecWrap(SEXP vector_)
        : vector(vector_)
    {
        type = vector.sexp_type();
        if (type != INTSXP && type != REALSXP) {
            Rcpp::stop("invalid type");
        }

    }

    bool contains(double val) {
        if (type == INTSXP){
            Rcpp::IntegerVector v = Rcpp::as<Rcpp::IntegerVector>(vector);
            for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
                if (v[i] == val) return true;
            }
        } else if (type == REALSXP) {
            Rcpp::NumericVector v = Rcpp::as<Rcpp::NumericVector>(vector);
            for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
                if (v[i] == val) return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
};

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::XPtr<VecWrap> createVecWrap(SEXP x) {
    return Rcpp::XPtr<VecWrap>(new VecWrap(x));
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
bool vecWrapContains(Rcpp::XPtr<VecWrap> w, double val) {
    return w->contains(val);
}
```

---

```
v <- 1:10e7
w <- createVecWrap(v)
vecWrapContains(w, 10000)
# [1] TRUE

rm(v)
gc()
#             used  (Mb) gc trigger   (Mb)  max used  (Mb)
# Ncells    366583  19.6     750400   40.1    460000  24.6
# Vcells 100559876 767.3  145208685 1107.9 100560540 767.3

vecWrapContains(w, 10000)
# [1] TRUE
```

---

Unrelated: consider using `{ }` for your control flow structures, and don't get carried away with `this->`; both of those will improve the readability of your code IMO.

Comment: I didn't know of RObject but it seems the perfect solution in this case, thanks! (PS I normally use `{ }` for control flow structures, in this case I just removed them to shorten the post, about `this->` instead I like to use it, but I know many people suggest otherwise...)