# using global SEXP to store XPtr gives garbage values

Tags: r, rcpp, r-package

I am building a package which solves Ordinary Differential Equations (ODEs) using the CVODE C routine (part of the SUNDIALS C library).

The package works if the user supplies a function which calculates derivatives and has the following form

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

#include <cvode/cvode.h>               /* prototypes for CVODE fcts., consts. */
#include <nvector/nvector_serial.h>    /* serial N_Vector types, fcts., macros */

int test (realtype t, N_Vector y, N_Vector ydot, void *user_data){

  // test function
  NV_Ith_S(ydot,0) = 1*NV_Ith_S(y,0);
  NV_Ith_S(ydot,1) = 2*NV_Ith_S(y,1);
  NV_Ith_S(ydot,2) = 3*NV_Ith_S(y,2);

  return(0);

} 

typedef int (*funcPtr)(realtype t, N_Vector y, N_Vector ydot, void *user_data);

// [[Rcpp::export]]
XPtr<funcPtr> putFunPtrInXPtr() {

  // return(XPtr<funcPtr> (new funcPtr(&test)));
  XPtr<funcPtr> testptr(new funcPtr(&test), false);
  return testptr;
```

A function pointer, i.e. `my_fun <- putFunPtrInXPtr()` is formed in `R` and `my_fun` is provided to the `cvode` function from the package (`cvode` inputs `my_fun` as an `SEXP`, see code [here](https://github.com/sn248/Rcppsbmod/blob/master/src/cvode.cpp)). *This works*, i.e. gives the right results (see detailed instructions [here](https://github.com/sn248/Rcppsbmod/wiki)). However, this requires that user has `SUNDIALS` installed on their system (to access `cvode.h` and `nvector_serial.h`).

I am trying to make the package so the user does not need to have `SUNDIALS` installed. So, the function to get derivatives (and generate function pointer) will be as below

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
typedef NumericVector (*funcPtr1) (double t, NumericVector y, NumericVector ydot);
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector test1 (double t, NumericVector y, NumericVector ydot){

  ydot[0] = 1 * y[0];
  ydot[1] = 2 * y[1];
  ydot[2] = 3 * y[2];

  return ydot;

}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
XPtr<funcPtr1> putFunPtrInXPtr1() {

    XPtr<funcPtr1> testptr1(new funcPtr1(&test1), false);
    return testptr1;

}
```

On the R side, `my_fun1 <- putFunPtrInXPtr1()` will be run and `my_fun1` will be provided to `cvode_test` (a test function defined in package to be able to handle derivative functions defined using `NumericVector` only.

In my package to convert function pointer type from `XPtr<funcPtr1>`to `XPtr<funcPtr>`, I do the following

1) A global `SEXP` (`sexp_g`) is defined outside any function
 2) In `cvode_test` the input `SEXP` is assigned to `sexp_g`
 3) Finally, a function `fun_test1` is defined as follows, which converts `N_Vector` to `NumericVector`, uses the function in `sexp_g` to get derivatives and then puts them again in an `N_Vector`, i.e.

```
typedef int (*funcPtr_test)(double time, NumericVector y, NumericVector ydot);

SEXP sexp_g;  // declare a global SEXP

int fun_test1(realtype t, N_Vector y, N_Vector ydot, void* user_data){

  // convert y to NumericVector y1
   int y_len = NV_LENGTH_S(y);

   NumericVector y1(y_len);    // filled with zeros
   for (int i = 0; i < y_len; i++){
     y1[i] = NV_Ith_S(y,i);
   }

  // use function pointer to get the derivatives
  XPtr<funcPtr_test> xpfun(sexp_g);
  funcPtr_test fun_test = *xpfun;

  NumericVector ydot1(y1.length());
  ydot1 = fun_test(t, y1, ydot1);

  // convert ydot1 to N_Vector ydot
  // N_Vector ydot; ydot = NULL;
  ydot = N_VNew_Serial(ydot1.length());
  for (int i = 0; i<ydot1.length(); i++){
    NV_Ith_S(ydot, i) = ydot1[i];
  }


  return (0);
}
```

Finally, in `cvode_test`, this `fun_test1` is used as follows

```
flag = CVodeInit(cvode_mem, fun_test1, T0, y0);
```

This also compiles but the issue is when I supply `my_fun1` (i.e., a pointer to `test1`) to `cvode_test` for integration, I get garbage values back. I am not sure what is going wrong here, I have read a few articles about protecting `SEXP` (i.e., the one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40225812/should-sexp-function-args-be-protected-when-put-inside-an-rcppxptr)) but I don't know how to implement it here.

Any help regarding what is wrong here, and if there is a better approach than a global `SEXP` variable will be helpful. Since the rhs function for `CVOdeInit` *has to have* the following signature

`int RHS_function (N_Vector, N_Vector, void*);`

I am finding it impossible to insert information in a function defined as above from a function defined outside the package using a different signature (using an `SEXP`), other than using a global variable and have been struggling with this problem for quite some time. Any help would be much appreciated!

A different approach that I have not tried is 1) declaring `XPtr<funPtr_test>` outside any function, 2) unwrapping `SEXP` to `XPtr<funcPtr_test>` inside the `cvode_test` and assigning it to the pointer declared outside the function. But I am struggling with the syntax to declare a function pointer of the type `XPtr<funcPtr_test>`.

The full code for `cvode` and `cvode_test` can be found [here](https://github.com/sn248/Rcppsbmod/blob/master/src/cvode.cpp)

Thanks

Comment: First, why are you using `false` in `XPtr<funcPtr1> testptr1(new funcPtr1(&test1), false);`?

Comment: See the comment by Romain here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47425715/using-xptr-to-create-pointer-to-a-user-defined-function-in-rcpp

Comment: In this post, Romain uses `true` (http://romainfrancois.blog.free.fr/index.php?post/2010/01/08/External-pointers-with-Rcpp). I've always seen `true`, this is why I asked. Same in http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp/Rcpp-modules.pdf (page 3).

Comment: Yes, I had it as 'true' before, but changed it based on Romain's comment. I am not exactly sure of its significance, except what Romain writes in his comments. I can try by switching to 'true'